# Перенос значения секундомера при переходе между страницами сайта

Tags: javascript, таймер

Построил секундомер что бы считал до 20 гектосекунд и 0 секунд
Но при переходе на другую страницу он обнуляется, как можно перенести насчитаное значение на другую страницу ?

Вот то что имееться

```js
const isLapsed1 = "isLapsed1" in localStorage;
const minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
const secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
const infoElement  = document.getElementById("info");
const info1Element  = document.getElementById("pervii16");

if(isLapsed1) {
 infoElement.hidden = false;
} else {
 const startTime = Date.now();
 
 (function loop() {

  const passedSeconds = 0.001 * (Date.now() - startTime);
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = parseInt(passedSeconds % 100).toString().padStart(1, "0");
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = parseInt(passedSeconds / 100).toString().padStart(1, "0");
  
  if(passedSeconds >= 2000) {
   infoElement.hidden = false;
   info1Element.hidden = true;
   localStorage.isLapsed1 = true;
  } else {
   infoElement.hidden = true;
   info1Element.hidden = false;
   setTimeout(loop, 500);
  }
 })();
}
```

```css
  .am-gift-block{}
    .am-gift-block__title{font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:700;color: #000000;font-size: 13px;line-height:14px;text-align:center;}
    .am-gift-block__healp{background-color: #fde344;border-radius:25px;width: 20px;color: #000;height: 20px;display:inline-block;line-height: 20px;cursor:pointer;position:relative;}
    .am-gift-block__healp-popup{width:256px;position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:32px;margin:0px;padding:10px 15px;opacity:0;z-index:200;font-size: 11px;line-height: 1.3;color: #fff;text-align:left;-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-khtml-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);-webkit-transition:opacity 0.15s ease 0s;-moz-transition:opacity 0.15s ease 0s;-o-transition:opacity 0.15s ease 0s;transition:opacity 0.15s ease 0s;}
    @media (min-width:1014px) and (max-width:1253px){
     .am-gift-block__healp-popup{width:182px;}
    }
    @media (min-width:788px) and (max-width:1013px){
     .am-gift-block__healp-popup{width:190px;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:787px){
     .am-gift-block__healp-popup{width:182px;}
     .am-gift-block__healp:hover .am-gift-block__healp-popup{left:-172px!important;}
     .am-gift-block__healp-popup::after{left:198px!important;}
    }
    .am-gift-block__healp:hover .am-gift-block__healp-popup{left:18px;opacity:1;}
    .am-gift-block__healp-popup::after{width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;top:-11px;left:4px;margin:0px;padding:0px;content:"";border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);border-right:11px solid transparent;-webkit-transition:all 0.15s ease 0s;-moz-transition:all 0.15s ease 0s;-o-transition:all 0.15s ease 0s;transition:all 0.15s ease 0s;}
    .am-gift{width:396px;margin:0px 0px 0px -198px;padding:0px;}
    @media screen and (max-width:787px){.am-gift{width:auto;margin:0px;}
    }
    .am-timer{background-color:#2FB519;background-image:url(/test/am-gift__icon.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: 10px 50%;border-radius:5px;margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 4px 0px 0px 40px;width: 135px;height: 40px;box-sizing:border-box;cursor:default;}
    .am-timer__block{margin:0 6px;float:left;text-align:center;}
    .am-timer__quantity{font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:700;color:#fff;font-size:18px;line-height:1;margin-bottom:1px;}
    .am-timer__unit{font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:400;color:#fff;font-size:12px;line-height:1;}
```

```html
    <div class="am-gift-block">
      <div class="am-gift-block__title">
        <div id="pervii16" hidden>Дарим пластик
        <span class="am-gift-block__healp">?<span class="am-gift-block__healp-popup">Пока крутится счетчик вы копите бесплатные метры пластика. Чтобы получить накопленный пластик - дождитесь максимального значения (20 метров), и следуйте инструкциям.</span></span>
        </div>
        <div id="info" hidden>Как получить ? 
          <a type="button" class="am-gift-block__healp" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="am-timer">
        <div class="am-timer__block">
          <div id="minutes" class="am-timer__quantity am-timer__quantity_unit_m">
            20
          </div>
          <div class="am-timer__unit">
            метров
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="am-timer__block">
          <div id="seconds" class="am-timer__quantity am-timer__quantity_unit_sm">
            0
          </div>
          <div class="am-timer__unit">
            см
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Во время инициализации секундомера, дополнительно, записывать время в куки. При загрузке страницы, проверять сохранённое  значение в куки и инициализировать им секундомер для продолжения отсчёта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов, хранить значение таймера в localStorage, а при переходе на новую страницу проверять и использовать сохраненное значение.

```
// Пишем значение таймера
let timerVal = 50;
localStorage.setItem('timerVal', timerVal);


// При загрузке достаем
let timerStorage = localStorage.getItem('timerVal');
```

Comment: Как реализовать в скрипт имеющийся ?